# Android - Create json object with asynctask

Tags: android, json

I've the following code :
(basically it creates various JSONObjects (beneficiario) and put them all inside another JSONObject (proposta). I don't show it here but I've Cursors (ppt, c) created before

```
            if (ppt.getString(45).equals("0")) {
                int i = 0;

                c.moveToFirst();
                JSONObject ben = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    while (c.isAfterLast() == false) 
                    {
                        i++;
                        ben.put("b_nome" + i, c.getString(1));
                        ben.put("b_telefone" + i, c.getString(2));
                        ben.put("b_nif" + i, c.getString(3));
                        ben.put("b_bi" + i, c.getString(4));
                        ben.put("b_codigopostal" + i, c.getString(5));
                        ben.put("b_localidade" + i, c.getString(6));
                        ben.put("b_morada" + i, c.getString(7));                        
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                proposta.put("beneficiario" + i, ben);
            }
```

And it gives a outofmemory error, I guess that's because I'm running it on main thread.
Can you give me an help/some code to use a thread or asynctask to do it?

Comment: shouldn't there be something like c.next() in your loop?

Comment: you should NEVER get `OutOfMemoryErrors` which are CAUSED by another Thread! You never call c.moveToNext() inside your While-loop. (As @M Mohsin Naeem suggested)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `c.moveToNext();` in your `While` loop. Your `Cursor` is running Infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Use async task something like this :

```
// You must provide types for the three generic parameters before the code will compile.          
// For more details, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html 
 private class MoveOutOfUIthread extends AsyncTask<
                Params, // one or more values of this type are passed to doInBackground()
                Progress, // the type of the progress units published during background crunching.
                Result // the type of the result returned by doInBackground()
                > 
 {

         protected Integer doInBackground(Params... p1, p2, p3) {
             // your background task here
             Result result = new Result();
             return result;
         }

         protected void onPostExecute(Result r) {
             // this gets the object returned by doInBackground, and executes on the UI thread
         }
 }
```

**Execute async task like this : **

```
new MoveOutOfUIthread().execute(p1, p2, p3);
```

its not intercessory to pass parameters you can simply do this :

```
new MoveOutOfUIthread().execute();
```

**NOTE :** You cannot change UI elements in `doInBackground`. You have to put the code in `onPreExecute` or `onPostExecute` which change the UI.

**UPDATE :**

This is to run your code in background thread. And as per your OutOfMemory error I think you should use `c.moveToNext();` in your while loop as `M Mohsin Naeem` answered.

Comment: right! but all that you mention doesn't trigger `OutOfMemoryErrors`

Comment: This is for what Luis Neves asked. He wants to move his code into a background thread. and as per his OutOfMemory error I updated my answer.